# How to solve bad smell with p-trap near exit

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, smell

I have a bad smell in the bathroom, sewer like smell.
Just moved in, but pretty sure that the bath, the separate shower and washbasin all lead into the same pipe, which descends into the cellar and joins the waste pipe from kitchen and then I presume the WC.

There's no p-trap under the wash basin just a small trap for waste but without resting water blocking gas. I presume same for shower, for the bath, don't have easy access so can't see.

I do have good access in the cellar so I wondered if it's possible to put a p-trap there as a catch all for any backup gases but that doesn't appear to be given on the net asa solution so asked myself why not?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally it isn't worth doing hacks or workarounds when dealing with a home.  If it is wrong update it or have a professional update it to modern codes/convention.
I'm not sure what you mean by a small trap for waste without standing water.  Do you maybe have a drum trap?

Comment: Is both the bath and separate shower used with regularity?  Perhaps they have separate traps and the unused has gone dry.  Make sure water is run into each drain regularly.

Comment: Yes a drum trap I think.

Comment: All are used regularly. So from that I took it that nothing had run dry.

Comment: Does updating mean lifting out the bath and fitting a new trap? There may not be room for such.

Comment: I wonder if there is a logical physical reason why not to make changes to the pipe at the exit point and not at the points of the fixtures. Thanks